# How to get all collections in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get a list of all existing collections in a Tensorflow model. Regarding collections automatically created by Tensorflow I can iterate over all keys in `GraphKeys` and can query each key e.g.

```
 tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAIN_OP)
```

Is there a way to get a complete list of all collections, including user created collections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tensorflow stores the collections as a private dictionary `_collections` in class `Graph`. This class also exposes a function to retrieve all collection keys/names:

```
tf.get_default_graph().get_all_collection_keys()
```